# Call function in redefining the function in R

Tags: r, function, recursion

I want to redefine my function in a loop by calling the function from last iteration. However I know this is basically a recursive way which I don't want. To give an example, see the following

```
for(i in 1:3)
{
...
myfunction<-function(y){myfunction(y)*dnorm(full_x[j],mean=y*full_x[j-1],sd=true_eps)}
...
result[[i]]<-myfunction
}
```

What I want is that in step t, I define a function called myfunction and in step t+1, I want to redefine the function by using myfunction from the last step in order to do some dynamic updatings. The program keeps giving me the error: "Error: C stack usage  7971152 is too close to the limit". I guess the problem lies in this "recursive way". I tried to relabel the function in each loop but it did not work. Is there any ways to solve this?

**A concrete example would be the following

```
# loop for calculating the density function
for(j in 2:length(full_x))
{

# define the normal density
trued<-function(y){dnorm(full_x[j],mean=y*full_x[j-1],sd=true_eps)}

# joint distribution
# which is normal density multiplied by a piror
if(j>=3)
{
  trued<- function(y){trued(y)**true_density(y)}
}

# integration of the density w.r.t. rho
trueint<-integrate(trued, lower = 0, upper = 1)$value

# density function 
true_density<-function(y) {trued(y)/trueint}

# save into list
dyn_density_true[[j-1]]<-true_density
}
```

What I want to do is to calculate a sequence of density functions. In the first step, it is just a normal density weighed by its integral (so posterior density). In the following steps, I need to use the density function from last step as a prior then do the same exercise again.

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what you're trying to do. Perhaps walk us throw and explicit & minimal example, where you show the old and new "function definitions". This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to `myfunction` directly when you want to refer to the latest entry in `result`. If you print `myfunction` or `result` you'll see why it doesn't work.

You can instead create a string with the actual function you want and then parse it. I've created a sample function below where each iteration multiplies the previous function result by 5.

```r
f <- function(y) y**2
k <- 5
res <- list(f)

for (i in 1:3) {

  fstring <- paste0('function(y) k*res[[',i,']](y)')
  res[[i+1]] <- eval(parse(text =  fstring))

}
res
#> [[1]]
#> function(y) y**2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> function(y) k*res[[1]](y)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> function(y) k*res[[2]](y)
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> function(y) k*res[[3]](y)
lapply(res,function(f) f(2))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 20
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 100
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 500
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>